Sci-Fi manga where murder victims go into rigor mortis seconds after death
This was the first volume of a manga I read around 2012-14. Humanity lives in advanced cities with a government highly influential in individual lives (I believe going so far as to assign jobs and schools to citizens). The main character is a school student who hears someone getting attacked. Either the body is already cold, or by the time he calls the police the body (which was bleeding seconds ago) is in rigor mortis. His crush either disappears shortly after, or is also found to be a victim of the murders.
Other details I recall, there was some sort of anti-government party being blamed for the murders, and the government was doing a cover-up around the bizarre details on the deaths.

No. 6 by Atsuko Asano

The story takes place in a dystopian city known as "No.6". Shion, a boy raised in the elite and privileged environment of his home, gives shelter to another boy, who only gives his name as "Nezumi" (or "Rat") on the former's twelfth birthday. What Shion soon discovers is how drastically life will change after meeting with the mysterious Nezumi, with whom he had shared one unforgettable, stormy night.

This review mentions the rapid rigor mortis:

Based on a sequence of light novels, the series is set in the city of No. 6, which on the surface at least seems idyllic: a crime rate of practically zero percent, cutting edge medical care, nature provided in a safe environment, and surrounded by huge walls to protect the city from outside threats. Shion is an ideal student living in the well-off part of the city, but on his twelfth birthday he helps an escaping criminal who calls himself “Rat”. Because of this, he and his mother are punished by being forcibly moved to the worst part of the city, and Shion’s studying is blocked.
Four years later, Shion is working in Park Maintenance looking after waste-disposal robots. One day he encounters a corpse that mysteriously has had rigor mortis set in after only a few minutes. Shion discovers that the cause of it is some form of disease, with large bee-like insects hibernating in humans, but not until after his boss dies too. The authorities try to frame Shion for murder, but then he reencounters Rat…

He has a female childhood friend, Safu, who attempts to bed him, but the primary romance is with Nezumi.
Found with a search for manga murder "rigor mortis"

That's the one! I totally forgot about Rat, which is funny considering his encounter is the inciting incident. Maybe now I can read past the first volume.

Hah... I went checking for dupes, and I provided this series as an (unaccepted) answer almost 5 years ago.

Curious as to how duplicate answers are decided: would this have been marked as a duplicate had the user accepted it as an answer? The old question is asking about the wasps and has no mention of the rigor mortis.

@Reeidly Yup. It's policy for story-identification that if the answers match, and both are acceptable, it's a dupe situation. The match does also have to be the same format (e.g. film and book are considered separate) and we generally separate series vs. individual piece.
